# Reactjs form is not reflecting changes on submission

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-forms

This is my code

```
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState(messagesList);

  const [addMessage, setAddMessage] = useState({
    messageSent: '',
  });

  const addMessageChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const fieldName = event.target.getAttribute("name");
    const fieldValue = event.target.value;
    const addMessageData = { ...addMessage };
    addMessageData[fieldName] = fieldValue;
    setAddMessage(addMessageData);
  };

  const addMessageSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newMessage = {
      id: 18,
      sender: "Aakanksha Mantri",
      textMessage: addMessage.messageSent,
      sentbyUser: true,
      time: "00:45",
    };

    const newMessages = [...messages, newMessage];
    setMessages(newMessages);
  };
```

```
<div className="chat-body">
        {messagesList.map((messageData) => (
          <div className={messageData.sentbyUser ? 'message-received' : 'message-sent'}>
            <p className="message-name">{messageData.sender}</p>
            {messageData.text} <span className="message-time">{messageData.time}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

```
<form onSubmit={addMessageSubmit}>
  <div className="message-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type a message" name="messageSent" onChange={addMessageChange}></input>
    <button type="submit">Send!</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Upon submitting, I would want the message entered to be added in the json file that contains the dummy data and has been imported. Also, the chat-body div should reflect the changes made on form submission.

Comment: you have `onChange {addMessageChange}`.. try `onChange={addMessageChange}`

Comment: "want the message entered to be added in the json file and then reflect the same in frontend" - What JSON file? What frontend? Not reflecting changes upon submission *where*? Please provide more details and be more specific. See [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese I have imported a json file which contains dummy data, upon form submission I would like the data to be appended to the json file and then be shows on the interface.

Comment: So you are updating some local state that was initialized from a static JSON file? Please share all the relevant code so we can see what it's trying to do.

Comment: @DrewReese sorry was a typo from my end, check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are updating local `messages` state but rendering the imported static JSON data.

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState(messagesList);

...

<div className="chat-body">
  {messagesList.map((messageData) => (
    <div className={messageData.sentbyUser ? 'message-received' : 'message-sent'}>
      <p className="message-name">{messageData.sender}</p>
      {messageData.text} <span className="message-time">{messageData.time}</span>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

The component should be mapping the `messages` state. Don't forget a valid React key on the mapped elements.

```
<div className="chat-body">
  {messages.map((messageData) => (
    <div
      key={messageData.id} // <-- or any unique property
      className={messageData.sentbyUser
        ? 'message-received'
        : 'message-sent'
      }
    >
      <p className="message-name">{messageData.sender}</p>
      {messageData.text} <span className="message-time">{messageData.time}</span>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

### Aside

I strongly suggest using [functional state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) whenever a component is updating state from a previous state.

```
const addMessageChange = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const { name, value } = event.target;

  setAddMessage(message => ({
    ...message,
    [name]: value
  }));
};

const addMessageSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const newMessage = {
    id: 18,
    sender: "Aakanksha Mantri",
    textMessage: addMessage.messageSent,
    sentbyUser: true,
    time: "00:45",
  };

  setMessages(messages => [...messages, newMessage]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand You this is what you want to reach, maybe you can change addMessage to be just a string for this purpose you don't need object with messageSent prop name because it is just a one string value state

```
  const [addMessage, setAddMessage] = useState({
    messageSent: '',
  });

  const addMessageChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const fieldValue = event.target.value;
    setAddMessage({messageSent: fieldValue})
  };

  const addMessageSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newMessage = {
      id: 18,
      sender: "Aakanksha Mantri",
      textMessage: addMessage.messageSent,
      sentbyUser: true,
      time: "00:45",
    };
    setMessages(old => [...old, newMessage])
  };
```